# CSS - Block object inline alongside text

Tags: html, css

I need an expand icon to go alongside a piece of dynamic text within a tab to show more info.  The expand icon has a background image - so needs to be displayed as block - when clicked a class is applied which alters the background image to a minus and the text beneath the link is revealed.

Is there a way to display the icon 5px to the left of the dynamic text and for it still to be a block (so you can see the background images)?

My HTML is below - note that the tab also contains a tick box which has a seperate function.

```
  <div class="expandLinkWO">Cardio &amp; Arms<span class="plusCircle btn"><span></span>     </span> <span class="tickBox"></span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use inline-block, which does what you want. Or you could make your button floating. Both should work.

**Inline-version**

```
.plusCircle {
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   margin-right: 5px;
}
```

**Float-version:**

```
.plusCircle {
   display:block;
   float:left;
   margin-right: 5px;
}
```

I believe the inline-block way is nicer, but IE and inline-block ain't the best of friends..

Comment: Cheers Tor - much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You probably need `inline-block` :

```
.plusCircle { 
    background: url(your/img/url.jpg);
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```